# Replace text output of mongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I'm running this query to obtain a certain data. The thing is, "chain" is a value of [0,1,2,3] which represents a string. Can I change the output for a hardcoded text? something like 0 = FOO, 1 = BAR, etc...

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "chain": "$chain"
      },
      "sum": {
        "$sum": "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": false,
      "chain": "$_id.chain",
      "sum": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "chain": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what do you mean 'chain' is a value of [0, 1, 2, 3] which represents a string?  It show as an array of integers, not strings...

Comment: it's one of those numbers, thought that was easy to infer. And each value i'd like to replace for something, like 1 for foo.

Comment: You might be able to use $expr or $switch.  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/   https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/